# Kafka broker taking too long to come up

Tags: apache-kafka

Recently, one of our Kafka broker (out of 5) got shut down incorrectly. Now that we are starting it up again, there are a lot of warning messages about corrupted index files and the broker is still starting up even after 24 hours. There is over 400 GB of data in this broker.

Although the rest of the brokers are up and running but some of the partitions are showing -1 as their leader and the bad broker as the only ISR. I am not seeing other Replicas to be appointed as new leaders, maybe because the bad broker is the only one in sync for those partitions.

```
Broker Properties: 
Replication Factor: 3
Min In Sync Replicas: 1
```

I am not sure how to handle this. Should I wait for the broker to fix everything itself? is it normal to take so much time?

Is there anything else I can do? Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After an unclean shutdown, a broker can take a while to restart as it has to do log recovery.

By default, Kafka only uses a single thread per log directory to perform this recovery, so if you have thousands of partitions it can take hours to complete.

To speed that up, it's recommended to bump `num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir`. You can set it to the number of CPU cores.

Comment: I left it overnight and everything came up and working in the morning.

I also bumped up the property num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir to 4.

Comment: In the documentation it says: 
`Due to the increased number of index files, on some brokers with large amount the log segments (e.g. >15K), the log loading process during the broker startup could be longer. Based on our experiment, setting the num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir to one may reduce the log loading time.`
So, they say that leaving at once reduced log loading time. Did you measure the speeding up of this process with 1 or higher-than-one value?

Comment: We did experiments to measure the recovery time for setting `num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir`. We tried it with 2 and 4. But it didn't had any effect on recovery time when compared to setting it to 1.